# Emacs how to render lslisting as verbatim

Tags: emacs

I am using `lstlisting` package in LaTeX-mode. Sometimes I have a $ symbol inside the code. Emacs treats it as the beginning of formula. And the rest of the document becomes ugly:

[image]

In verbatim mode it renders special symbols correctly:

[image]

How to make it render lslisting as verbatim?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Add `"lstlisting"` to `LaTeX-verbatim-environments` (using `M-x customize-variable`) and *reopen your file*.

```
LaTeX-verbatim-environments is a variable defined in `latex.el'.
Its value is ("verbatim" "verbatim*" "lstlisting")
Original value was ("verbatim" "verbatim*")

Documentation:
Verbatim environments.
```

Comment: Sir, how can I read the documentation of LaTeX-mode you are referring to?

Comment: `M-x describe-variable <RET> LaTeX-verbatim-environments`. The problem is finding the right variable :) I grepped `verbatim` in aucTeX sources.